# Autocomplete that returns "city" using jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, spring-mvc

I have made two selects box  'State' and 'City'.  Here the value of branch populates based on state. Here are the code snippets which help me do that.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getBranchlist.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")

    public  @ResponseBody String getBranchList(@RequestParam("state")String state) {

          ApplicationContext context = 
                     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

          MasterJDBCTemplate dao = 
                  (MasterJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("masterJDBCTemplate");

           List<String> fans = dao.getBranchList(state);
           String branch = "";
           for(String fan : fans)
           branch+=fan+",";
           if(branch.length()== 0){
               branch = "";
           }else{
           branch = branch.substring(0, branch.length() - 1);
           }
           return branch;
    }
```

and the jQuery code

```
$(function(){
     $("#state").change(function(){
      var state = $("#state").val();
      $.get("getBranchlist.htm",{ "state":state},function( data ) { 
            var target = $("#branch");
            target.find('option').remove();
            target.append($('<option/>').val("").text("---Select"));
            if(data == ""){
                return false;
            }
            var opts = data.split(',');
            $.each(opts, function(i, opt){
                   target.append(
                            $('<option/>').val(jQuery.trim(opt)).text(jQuery.trim(opt)));
            });  
      });
  });
});
```

This works fine this is as far as i got.

I have tried using the autocomplete (display all the branches in database)feature as shown here ---> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

so i tried doing this

```
$(function() {
$( "#branch" ).autocomplete({ source: "getBranchlist.htm" });
}
```

However i do not get the output. I think i will have to make few changes in controller to return 'JSON'. What my controller should return ? In what format ? Say if i want to show 'Ohio', 'Milan' , 'Sydney'.

Comment: Do i have to wrap it up in a some kind of JSON related object ? Or just returning the above string will help me achieve what i want to..

Comment: You need to return valid JSON. This string is valid JSON: `["Ohio", "Milan", "Sydney"]`, the one I posted earlier is not since it used single quotes.

Comment: I have to send something like this ? ["Mumbai , Maharashtra" , "Kolkata , West Bengal"] .. The use of comma ',' will not cause any problem ?  Will it  ??